# Why is reCAPTCHA causing my PHP mail function to not work?

Tags: php, email, recaptcha

I recently noticed that the send mail forms on all my websites stopped working. I removed the reCAPTCHA code and it worked again. After some research, I realized I was using Google's old reCAPTCHA v1.0 so I figured maybe that was the problem. Although after setting up reCAPTCHA v2.0 I'm running into the same problem. The reCAPTCHA works to some extent, because I still receive the message, "This statement was executed" when I check it and get the error message, "Please go back and make sure you complete the security CAPTCHA" when I don't, yet it won't send out the email.

**Note:** I have checked my spam folder. The PHP code is at the top of the page (not sure if that even matters). Email sends exactly as it should without the reCAPTCHA code.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$privatekey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxPRIVATExKEYxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$response = file_get_contents($url.'?secret='.$privatekey.'&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].'&remoteip'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$data = json_decode($response);

if (isset($data->success) AND $data->success == true) {

    $senderEmail = $_POST["emailfeed"];
    $recipient = "myemail@gmail.com";
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $headers = "From: Feedback <$senderEmail>\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

    $body ='Hello World';

    mail($recipient,$subject,$body,$headers);
    echo 'This statement was executed.';

} else {
    echo '<p>Please go back and make sure you complete the security CAPTCHA.</p>';
} ?>
```

**Edit:** I still haven't figured it out, but through testing I have narrowed it down to the line of code that's causing the problem. It has to do with the text within the file_get_contents() function. For some reason, the url request is causing the mail function to not work. Although, the url seems to be correct because the recaptcha still works, just not the mail function.

**Edit: PROBLEM SOLVED!** It seems the problem may have been caused by sending the data as a GET request using a url rather than POST. I originally followed a YouTube tutorial and while it worked for them, it did not work for me because I required the use of the mail() function. Shout out to Ramse from reddit (r/phphelp) who helped me figure this out! Here is the working code:

```
<?php
function post_captcha($user_response) {
    $fields_string = '';
    $fields = array(
        'secret' => '---------PRIVATE--KEY----------',
        'response' => $user_response
    );
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value)
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    $fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return json_decode($result, true);
}

// Call the function
$res = post_captcha($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
echo $res.'<br><br>';

if(!$res['success']){
    // If not captcha isn't successfully completed
    echo 'Please go back and make sure you check the security CAPTCHA box.<br><br>';
} else {
    // If captcha is successfully completed
    $senderEmail = "senderemail@gmail.com";
    $recipient = "recipient@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Example Subject";
    $headers = "From: Feedback <$senderEmail>";

    $body = $_POST["messagefeed"];

    mail($recipient,$subject,$body,$headers);

    echo 'Your message has been sent!<br><br>';
}
```

?>

Comment: What is `$data`. Can you `var_dump($data);`?

Comment: @McStuffins When I var_dump($data) upon completion of captcha I get 
`object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["success"]=> bool(true) ["challenge_ts"]=> string(20) "2016-12-10T08:46:09Z" ["hostname"]=> string(21) "makingspidersense.com" } `

Comment: And if left incomplete the output is 
`object(stdClass)#1 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["error-codes"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(22) "missing-input-response" } } `